# Add a DIV below hovered image with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I currently have a mouseover/mouseout event - I want to show a div after the animation is complete on mouseover, and hide the div before the animation begins on mouseout.

I can't get it to display relative to the div shown after animation, or queue it correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/q2Fh7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the callback function parameters of `animate()` to append the `message` div to the relevant `box`. You should also use `hover` for this. Try this:

```
$('.box').hover(
    function() {
        var $box = $(this);
        $box.stop().animate(
            { width: '280px', height: '420px'},
            650,
            function() {
                var $div = $("<div></div>").addClass("message").text("Message text");
                $box.append($div);
                $div.fadeIn();
            }
        );
    },
    function() {
        var $box = $(this);
        $(".message", $box).fadeOut(function() {
            $box.stop().animate({ width: '100px', height: '100px' }, 650);
        });        
    }
);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q2Fh7/26/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is not exactly what you want. But I figure it will get you on the right path:
http://jsfiddle.net/r6xbp/

Edit: optimized
http://jsfiddle.net/r6xbp/2/